# Adding row AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, row, addition

Function:

```js
angular.module('formTerm', [])
  .controller('MainController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {

        $scope.rows = [{
          explanation: '',
          example: ''
        }];
        $scope.counter = 5;
        $scope.addRow = function() {
          $scope.rows.push({
            explanation: '',
            example: ''
          });
          $scope.counter++;
        }
```

HTML :

```html
<span class="add btn btn-primary" ng-click="addRow()">Add</span>
<div class="template term-row" ng-repeat="rows in rows">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="explanation" placeholder="Explanation" name="explanation" ng-model="formData.rows.explanation"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="example" placeholder="Example" name="example" ng-model="formData.rows.example"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <br />
</div>
```

Someone please help. The row was added but I want it in different element name such as "explanation1@explanation2@explanation3" etc.

Please have a look at [the sample](http://codepen.io/AhmadMorse/pen/hKina)

Comment: Next time, try to write a more descriptive question. At the time of writing this comment, there is 3 answers and each of those tries to solve a different problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. please look at the sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned your inputs models to the variables `formData.rows.explanation` and `formData.rows.example` - so simply put them as the value.

This should do the trick:

```
$scope.counter = 5;
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.rows.push({
        explanation: $scope.formData.rows.explanation,
        example: $scope.formData.rows.example
    });
    $scope.counter++;
}
```

Comment: it's not working. the row added, but when I put an input to explanation field, it's show to  every rows.. same happened to example field..

Answer (score 0):

Use `$index`, Since $index will start from 0 we will need to add +1 to it.

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="explanation{{$index + 1}}" placeholder="Explanation" name="explanation{{$index + 1}}" ng-model="formData.rows.explanation"></textarea>
```